# Catching an error based on unique id values in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, function, error-handling

I want to create a `stop()` for my data.frame below such that for each unique `id`, if `pos` is varying (e.g., consisting of 1s, 2s,etc.), then, if `mp` values for the rows for which `cont==TRUE` are not the same, we should throw an error.

Is this possible in R?

In the below toy example, `id == "B"` should throw an error because, `pos` is varying (1,2,3), and `mp` values (i.e., 1,3) for the rows for which `cont==TRUE` are not the same.

```
dat <- data.frame(id = rep(c("A","B"),2:3), mp = c(1,5, 2,1,3), cont = c(F,T, F,T,T), pos = c(1,1, 1:3))
#  id mp  cont pos
#1  A  1 FALSE   1
#2  A  5  TRUE   1
#3  B  2 FALSE   1
#4  B  1  TRUE   2
#5  B  3  TRUE   3

# Desired stop() message:
"Error: 'B' has a wrong value."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `base R`, one option is to `split` the subset of data i.e where 'cont' is TRUE by 'id' into a `list`.  Then loop over the `list` along with the `names` of the `list` in `Map`, check `if` the `unique` rows have more than 1 row, then call the `stop`

```
lst1 <- split(dat[dat$cont,c("mp", "pos")], dat$id[dat$cont])
Map(function(x, y) if(nrow(unique(x)) > 1)  
     stop(sprintf("'%s' has a wrong value.", y), call. = FALSE), 
        lst1, names(lst1))
#Error: 'B' has a wrong value.
```

---

With the updated example

```
lst1 <- split(dat[dat$control, c("mpre", "post")], dat$study.name[dat$control])
Map(function(x, y) if(all(lengths(lapply(x, unique))  > 1))  
      stop(dQuote(sprintf("'%s' has a wrong value.", y), FALSE), call. = FALSE), 
         lst1, names(lst1))
#Error: "'Brown' has a wrong value."
```

Comment: @rnorouzian can you test my updated solution.  Also check `lst1[["Brown"]]`

Comment: @rnorouzian please note that `stop` will execute at the first occurence of that issue and throw the error.  It won't show you all the ids having the problem

Comment: Arun, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67563791/7223434) might be of interest.