# Creating error message for each id value in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, function, error-handling

I'm following up on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67542683/catching-an-error-based-on-unique-id-values-in-a-data-frame/67542715?noredirect=1#comment119384000_67542715) question. I want to create a `stop()` for my data.frame below. Specifically, for each unique `id` value, if `pos` is varying (e.g., consisting of 1s, 2s,etc.), then for each unique value of `out` (e.g., 1) under each `id`, if `mp` values for the rows for which `cont==TRUE` are not the same, we should throw an error.

Is this possible in R?

In the below toy example, `id == "B"` should throw an error because, `pos` is varying (1,2,3), and for each unique value of `out` (e.g., 1) under `id == "B"`, `mp` values for the rows for which `cont==TRUE` are not the same.

```
dat <- data.frame(id=rep(c("A", "B"), c(2, 6)), mp=c(1, 5, 2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 0), 
                  cont=c(F, T, F, F, T, T, T, T), pos=c(1, 1, rep(1:2, 3)),
                  out=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2))


#  id mp  cont pos out
#1  A  1 FALSE   1   1
#2  A  5  TRUE   1   1
#3  B  2 FALSE   1   1
#4  B  1 FALSE   2   1
#5  B  3  TRUE   1   1
#6  B  4  TRUE   2   1
#7  B  6  TRUE   1   2
#8  B  0  TRUE   2   2

# Desired stop() message:
"Error: 'B' has a wrong value."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this.

```
sapply(split(dat, dat$id), function(x) {
  if (var(x[,'pos']) > 0) {
    r <- all(sapply(unique(x[,'out']), function(i)
      var(x[x[,'out'] == i & x[,'cont'], 'mp']) > 0))
  } else {
    r <- FALSE
  }
  if (r) {
    stop(sprintf("Error: '%s' has a wrong value.", x[,'id'][1]))
  }
})
# Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Error: 'B' has a wrong value.
```

Comment: Isn't OP mentioning to consider unique value of 'out' (e.g., 1) under each 'id' as well?

Comment: @Reza Probably you're right and it's more nested. OP is not very easy to read though. Updated.

Comment: Both accepted and +1 for use of `var`, thank you!

Comment: I have asked a follow-up [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67596880/7223434) in case interested.

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
lst1 <- split(dat[dat$cont,c("mp", "pos")], dat$id[dat$cont])
Map(function(x, y) if(nrow(unique(x)) > 1)  
     stop(sprintf("'%s' has a wrong value.", y), call. = FALSE), 
        lst1, names(lst1))
#Error: 'B' has a wrong value.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very verbose answer, hope it's useful.

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  filter(cont) %>%

  group_by(id, out) %>%
  mutate(varying_mp = n_distinct(mp) > 1) %>%
  
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(varying_pos = n_distinct(pos) > 1,
         all_varying_mp = min(varying_mp)) %>%
  
  filter(varying_pos & all_varying_mp) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  pull(id) -> wrong_val_ids


if(!is.null(length(wrong_val_ids))) stop(paste("Error: ", paste(wrong_val_ids, collapse = ","), "has a wrong value"))
```