# Follow-up: Creating error message for each id value in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, function, error-handling

I'm following up on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67544576/7223434) answer. I want to create a `stop()` for my data.frame below. Specifically, for each unique `id` value, if `pos` is varying (i.e., is not constant), then **for any unique value of `out` (e.g., 1) under each `id`**, if any `mp` values for the rows for which `cont==TRUE` are not the same, we should throw an error.

Is this possible in BASE R?

In the below toy example, `id == "B"` should throw an error because, `pos` is varying (1,2,3), and for the unique value of `out == 2` under `id == "B"`, `mp` values (rows 7 & 8) which are the rows for which `cont==TRUE` are not the same (i.e., `5` and `6`).

My current solution doesn't capture this error (below).

```
(dat <- data.frame(id=rep(c("A", "B"), c(2, 6)), mp=c(1, 5, 2, 3, 1, 1, 5, 6), 
                  cont=c(F, T, F, F, T, T, T, T), pos=c(1, 1, rep(1:2, 3)),
                  out=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2)))
#  id mp  cont pos out
#1  A  1 FALSE   1   1
#2  A  5  TRUE   1   1
#3  B  2 FALSE   1   1
#4  B  3 FALSE   2   1
#5  B  1  TRUE   1   1
#6  B  1  TRUE   2   1
#7  B  5  TRUE   1   2
#8  B  6  TRUE   2   2

# Desired stop() message:
"Error: 'B' has a wrong value."

## My current solution (doesn't `stop()`):

sapply(split(dat, dat$id), function(x) {
  if (var(x[,'pos']) > 0) {
    r <- all(sapply(unique(x[,'out']), function(i)
      var(x[x[,'out'] == i & x[,'cont'], 'mp']) > 0))
  } else {
    r <- FALSE
  }
  if (r) {
    stop(sprintf("Error: '%s' has a wrong value.", x[,'id'][1]))
  }
})
```

## UPDATE:

To follow-up, if we had an additional column called `sp`, and wanted the exact same condition for `sp` as we did for `mp`, how would `@kews` solution change?

```
(NEW_dat <- data.frame(id=rep(c("A", "B"), c(2, 6)), mp=c(1, 5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 6), 
                   sp=c(.2, .3, .2, .2, .2, .2, .6, .5),
                 cont=c(F, T, F, F, T, T, T, T), pos=c(1, 1, rep(1:2, 3)),
                  out=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2)))
#  id mp  sp  cont pos out
#1  A  1 0.2 FALSE   1   1
#2  A  5 0.3  TRUE   1   1
#3  B  2 0.2 FALSE   1   1
#4  B  1 0.2 FALSE   2   1
#5  B  1 0.2  TRUE   1   1
#6  B  1 0.2  TRUE   2   1
#7  B  6 0.6  TRUE   1   2
#8  B  6 0.5  TRUE   2   2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This follows the logic in the question.

```
for (x in split(dat, dat$id)) {
  pos_constant <- (length(unique(x$pos)) == 1)
  if (pos_constant) {
    next
  }
  group_out <- split(x,x$out)
  for (x_sub in group_out) {
    mps <- x_sub[x_sub$cont==TRUE,"mp"]
    mps_constant <- (length(unique(mps)) %in% c(1,0))
    if (!mps_constant) {
      stop(sprintf("'%s' has a wrong value.", x[,"id"][1]))
    }
  }
}
```

Edit:
Added control flow to check identical condition on `sp` column, the same thing with the exact same `*_constant` logic.

```
for (x in split(dat, dat$id)) {
  pos_constant <- (length(unique(x$pos)) == 1)
  if (pos_constant) {
    next
  }
  group_out <- split(x,x$out)
  for (x_sub in group_out) {
    mps <- x_sub[x_sub$cont==TRUE,"mp"]
    sps <- x_sub[x_sub$cont==TRUE,"sp"]
    mps_constant <- (length(unique(mps)) %in% c(1,0))
    sps_constant <- (length(unique(sps)) %in% c(1,0))
    if (!mps_constant | !sps_constant) {
      stop(sprintf("'%s' has a wrong value.", x[,"id"][1]))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! To follow-up, if we had an additional column called `sp`, and wanted the exact same condition for `sp` as we did for `mp`, how would your solution change? I updated my question with `NEW_dat`.